# authorise('core.admin') how to include administrator level also?

Tags: joomla-3.9, access

We want Administrators to be able to see Privacy Requests in the module on `cpanel`. But this module has the following code:

```
// Only super user can view this data
if (!JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.admin'))
{
    return;
}
```

What is the safest way to add 'Administrator' access as well. Commenting the above out and setting up the permissions from within the Joomla Backend Module Parameters or should we replace the 'core.admin' to `core.edit`?

PS: We are strictly talking about the CPanel Module not the entire Privacy Suite!

PS2: We know that making changes to core modules can revert after updates.

PS3: If this is extremely unsafe then please let us know.

PS4: We don't like to go the route of the 'MagicNumbers' as in this example. Because the groups can change but if it is the only viable solution then we have to go with it.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->groups;

if (in_array(7, $groups)):

 //only enter if the user is in the group 7 (group 7 = Administrator)

endif;
```

Comment: Regarding your PS4 "groups can change": I understand that you do not like to use the Group IDs. However it's very unlikely that your Super Admin + Administrator group ID will change. The default Joomla ACL has been configured to use those by default. 

The "names" of those groups ("Administrator" & "Super Administrator") are more likely to be changed.

I would check on Group ID. If you check for ID = 7 (Administrator), do not forget to check for ID = 8 too (Superadministrator).

Comment: Yeah, I went with the PS4 option as I could not find another way to do it. I added both the 7 and 8. Was just hoping there was another way to do it though.